# changing input type image in a form by an input type text

Tags: jquery, form-submit, replacewith, submit-button

I'm using paypal on my wesbite, with generated code from the paypal website.
I want to change some parts of this code because I want to remove the paypal "add to cart" default image by a custom text, using jquery.

here is the original part of code :

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

and I would like to change this by this custom code :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add To Cart" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

can anyone help me with this ?

here is a jsfiddle with the original paypal button and with the text to replace the button,

http://jsfiddle.net/DKHR4/1/

thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Just css-up your submit button and remove the input[type=image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
$('input[type="image"][name="submit"][alt]').replaceWith('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add To Cart" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">');
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVVR8/)